# Is H a normal subgroup in G?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

> Let $G = S_5$ and let $H = \langle(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)\rangle$. Is $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$ ?

Having some trouble figuring out this problem, it would be great if someone can help to find it!

Comment: What would happen if you conjugate generator by any transposition?

Comment: @ Sunny Rathore im not sure.I'm new to the group theory.

Comment: What are h and i in the problem statement? Are they just denoting brackets?

Comment: @Chickenmancer: that was by mistake, edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $(12)(12345)(12)=(13452)\not\in\langle (12345)\rangle =\{e,(12345),(13524),(14253),(15432)\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Chris Custer provides an answer by using definition but I hope the following is useful to you for finding normal subgroups in $S_n$

---

**Hint:**  A subgroup $H$ of $G$ is normal $\iff$ $H$ is the union of conjugacy classes
$$\&$$ Remember that, elements of $S_n$ are conjugate $\iff$ they have the same cycle type